# Console.log filled with "stopping Handoff advertising"

Tags: macos, console, continuity

My console.log is filled with "stopping Handoff advertising" messages, I counted 29 in the last 3 minutes. I also get the occasional:

> 10/24/14 01:21:35.089 lsuseractivityd[245]: -[LSUserActivityClientProcess doUpdateUserActivityInfo:makeCurrent:completionHandler:], refusing to register user activity from client, and returning error Error Domain=LSContinuityErrorDomain Code=-108 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSContinuityErrorDomain error -108.)" for item <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7ffe10c1f0a0> [redacted]-[redacted]-[redacted]-[redacted]-[redacted] NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb (LSUserActivityClientProcess.m #1148)

Is this normal or expected behavior?

Update, from my comment below:

> Thanks for the help. Looking at it, my console is *full* of all sorts of error logs. I've Googled each and every one of them, and most resulted in the *same* threads about Yosemite. At this point, I prefer to wait for 10.10.1 to see what's fixed as my machine is running mostly fine.

Comment: could you expand your Console log please.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looking at it, my console is *full* of all sorts of error logs. I've Googled each and every one of them, and most resulted in the *same* threads about Yosemite. At this point, I prefer to wait for 10.10.1 to see what's fixed as my machine is running mostly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure do clear your browser's cookies and history.

But with your limited Console log it could be this.

> Yosemite is designed to handoff integrated app statuses to other Apple
>   devices, the "advertising" may simply refer to the fact that my
>   Yosemite Mac is advertising that there is stuff to handoff to an iOS 8
>   device, but that functionality is not yet implemented

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:   http://asdfsafds.blogspot.com/2014/11/yosemite-log-shows-sharingd-stopping.html

Preferences> General> Uncheck "Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices"